# Can't set select option as default

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, combobox

I am trying to set a default option in a select menu from the local storage, I am using a GUID as the value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var guid = getParameterByName("dashId");

        //$("#cboDashboards").val(guid); - Attempt #1 
        //$("#cboDashboards > option[value=" + guid + "]").prop("selected", true); - Attempt #2
        //jQuery('#cboDashboards > option[value="' + guid + '"]').prop('selected', true) - Attempt #3
    });

    document.getElementById("cboDashboards").onchange = function () {
        localStorage.dashboardGuid = this.value;
        window.location.href = "/Home/Index?dashId=" + this.value;
    };
</script>
```

The GUID that gets stored is the same as the GUID that I try to populate the combo box with, however, I have tried three different methods of trying to populate the combo box and none have worked. Any suggestions to why this isn't working as expected?

EDIT -
Would this method have any effect on it? It's called to populate the combo box with the values:

```
function populateDashboard(data) {
    var options = $("#cboDashboards");

    $.each(data, function () {
        options.append($("<option />").val(this.DashboardGuid).text(this.Name));
    });
}
```

I populated some test data -

```
<select  id="cboDashboards">
    <option value="0">Select dashboard</option>
    <option value="1">Select dashboard 1</option>
    <option value="2">Select dashboard 2</option>
    <option value="3">Select dashboard 3</option>
    @* <option value="0">Select dashboard</option>*@
</select>
```

and I did :

$("#cboDashboards").val('1'); // - Attempt #1

This worked, so I seem to be having a problem with the GUID value?

Comment: I think I found the problem. You are calling selection function before load all options

Comment: What do you suggest then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with jQuery using this code:

```
function populateDashboard(data) {
    var options = $("#cboDashboards");

    $.each(data, function () {
        options.append($("<option />").val(this.DashboardGuid).text(this.Name));
    });

    var guid = getParameterByName("dashId");
    //select element
    $('#cboDashboards option[value='+ guid +']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Nope, same problem, the first option is still being selected.

Comment: try this before select the element: $('#cboDashboards option').removeAttr('selected');

Comment: There is a lot of C# code running in the background which is used to populate the combo boxes, I'm wondering if because I am using a GUID, it might be effecting it

Comment: Maybe you are missing something. I have created a fiddle and it works http://jsfiddle.net/ujn5mhq3/

Comment: Yeah, I made a change to my post, if I have the values manually populated, it works fine, it's just when I automatically populate the values myself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61771/discussion-between-jessica-and-ragnar).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Cheers :)